# Negation Not in C

Tags: c

im trying to prcosee an incoming string and checking to see if its previous character was in a certian range after passing a previous test. something like

```
if current charcter is in range A-Z and previous character was not in range A-Z
```

so i wrote the above statement as

```
if ('A'<= s[i]&& s[i] <= 'Z')
else if ('A'!<= s[i-1]&& s[i-1] !<= 'Z')
```

but i get an error stating expected'<' before ! token. so what would be the correct way to write this statement? The purpose of this is to check each character in an incoming string.  i have turned everything capitalized so if one character is in the range but the character before it was not, the the count for wordcount will increase

Comment: If it is `not less or equal than A`, than logically it means that it is `higher than A` :-)

Comment: `isupper(s[i]) && !isupper(s[i-1])`

Answer (score 2):

In C, "not" does not work this way: you do not write `'A'!<= s[i-1]`, you write either

```
'A' > s[i-1]     // negate using math
```

or

```
!('A' <= s[i-1]) // negate with ! operator (less readable)
```

Note that to negate an "AND" expression you should negate its parts, and also replace "AND" with "OR":

```
else if ('A' > s[i-1] || s[i-1] > 'Z')
```

(the fancy name for this little trick is [*De Morgan's Laws*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

Answer (score 1):

There's no such operator `!<=`, the negation of `<=` is simply `>`.

```
else if ('A' > s[i-1] || s[i-1] > 'Z')
```

And in logic arithmetic, `A and B`'s negation is `(not A) or (not B)`.

Comment: Not really. You need to replace the `&&` with `||`(have a look at the actual problem being solved).

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this:

```
if ('A' <= s[i] && s[i] <= 'Z')
else if ('A' > s[i-1] || s[i-1] > 'Z')
```

The *"negation"* of `>=` is simply `<` and the negation of `<=` is `>`.

Comment: Not really. You need to replace the `&&` with `||`(have a look at the actual problem being solved).

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev true, rushed to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if there was such a conditional operator as `!>=` your statement is not write as the negation of `&&` is in fact `||`. You can use the operator `!` in front of the whole statement:

```
if ('A'<= s[i]&& s[i] <= 'Z')
else if (! ('A'<= s[i-1]&& s[i-1] <= 'Z'))
```

Or you can think a bit of which operators are logically opposite to `>=` and `<=`:

```
if ('A'<= s[i]&& s[i] <= 'Z')
else if ('A' > s[i-1] || s[i-1] > 'Z')
```

By the way in both cases you should replace the `else if` with a simple `if`. You need to perform an operation if and only if both statements: `('A'<= s[i]&& s[i] <= 'Z')` and `('A' > s[i-1] || s[i-1] > 'Z')` are true.

Answer (score 0):

As logical equations grow, the chance for error or mis-understanding grows.

Suggest using a macro or helper function for clear code.

```
#define INRANGE(lo, x, hi)  ((lo) >= (x) && (x) <= (hi))
if (INRANGE('A', s[i], 'Z') && (i > 0) && !INRANGE('A', s[i-1], 'Z')) { ...

// or simply as suggested by @rmartinjak
#include <ctype.h> 
if (isupper(s[i]) && (i > 0) && !isupper(s[i-1])) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing a stream you would look at s[i-1] before s[i] 
    `if 'A' > s[i] || 'Z' < s[i] then process s[i++] if s[i++] within A-Z found so break out of loop else i++ then loop back to first if test`